# Full screenshot of a window

Tags: delphi, winapi, screenshot

I am using this code to create a screenshot of a specified window **(either active or not)**.

```
function WndScreen(const h: HWND; const bmp: TBitmap): boolean;
var
  Src, Dst: HDC;
  R: TRect;
  Width, Height: Integer;
  B: HBITMAP;
  Old: HGDIOBJ;
begin
  Src := GetDC(h);
  GetWindowRect(h, R);
  Width := R.Right - R.Left;
  Height := R.Bottom - R.Top;
  Dst := CreateCompatibleDC(Src);
  B := CreateCompatibleBitmap(Src, Width, Height);
  Old := SelectObject(Dst, B);
  BitBlt(Dst, 0, 0, Width, Height, Src, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  SelectObject(Dst, Old);
  DeleteDC(Dst);
  ReleaseDC(h, Src);

  bmp.Width := Width;
  bmp.Height := Height;
  bmp.Handle := B;

  DeleteObject(B);
end;
```

Now let's say that the window has a combobox. When I click on the combobox and expand the list, the list content is not included in my screenshot.

Do you know of any method to create a full window screenshot?

Comment: Any reason why Alt+PtrScr isn't utilised?

Comment: I want to programatically create a screenshot of a window, that's why.

Comment: You could do whatever a full-screen capture does, and then use the coordinates of your window to crop out what you want.

Comment: Unless the bounds of the combo box extend beyond the bounds of the parent window, @Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`PrintWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162869.aspx) function instead of using `BitBlt()` directly.  Despite its name, `PrintWindow()` can be used for capturing screenshots to a bitmap, it is not limited to just printing.